# Application Project gets "Could not load file or assembly" while the project being referenced tests fine

Tags: c#

I have the following library project: https://github.com/RFBProducts/ClickOnceApplicationDeployment
which references this project: https://github.com/derskythe/WpfSettings
which finally references this nuget package: https://gitlab.com/Syroot/KnownFolders

In the upper two references there is a test app that is essentially a small WPF window with a few buttons that is used to validate the libraries are working as intended. They work perfect as far as I can tell. I have modified the top level project above to include the dll's into the nuget package that is built since the middle project never had a nuget package submitted for it. This was working (keyword was)

My current project that I am working on though is having a meltdown over it. (Clarity Edit: This application will use the 'ClickOnceApplicationDeployment' project linked above) I am getting the following error whenever I try to use a static method provided by the library:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Syroot.KnownFolders, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

The dll that is failing to load is required by the middle dll.

I find this extremely annoying, since no matter what I do I cannot get this to resolve. I have tried the following:

- Restart Visual Studio about 50 times
- Remove the NugetPackage for the SyRoot.KnownFolders from the assemblies and switch to Microsoft's KnownFolders assembly
- Remove all references to external assemblies to get the known folders and isntead build the source code into the middle project that calls it so its no longer an external reference.
- Clone the repo for the KnownFolders project and add the references in to both other projects
- Copy the dll into directly into the application's projects folder that all the other dlls get stuffed into during compiling.
- Clean and rebuild too many times to count.

No matter what, even if the nuget package / project is no longer referenced, I am getting that 'could not load assembly' exception when running my application.

Call in question:

```
RFBApplicationDeployment.ClickOnceApplicationDeployment.SetupEntryApplication(@"P:\MyPublishPath");
```

I can't even step through the code, since it is throwing the exception before it even gets to the command that supposedly missing dll. Here is the CTOR that the method above calls. THe highlighted line is the line that calls the dll. BUT I can't even enter the CTOR when stepping through the code, it errors out before that.

[image]

Regarding potential duplicate entries: I've read multiple and nothing has helped resolve it.

When testing the 'TestApp' project though (which would technically be a 4th level project for this purpose), everything works fine for the 3rd level project. But the actual application i'm building as the 4th level project errors out? (4th being the application, and 3rd being the dll that houses the static method the application calls)

Answer (score 0):

I was being tired and dumb.
I needed to add the reference to my main project since it wasn't automatically added and wasn't included in the dll the linked projects above provided.

I have since updated the linked projects into a single dll to overcome this error for future consumption